# Having trouble figuring out how to place code into kotlin and use a method channel to send functions from flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

My MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL = "flutter.native/helper"
    private var mapId: Int? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, PersistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, PersistentState)

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine(this));

    }
    
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "KML") {
                result.success(getKMLResource());
            } else {
                result.notImplemented();
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getKMLResource(): Int {
        return R.raw.borders;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to insert the below call, but I get a errors every time.

```
override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    when (call.method) {
        "showToast" -> {
            val text = call.argument<String>("text") // hello world
            showToast(text)
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
'onMethodCall' overrides nothing
One type argument expected for class Result<out T>
Unresolved reference: showToast
```

Here's my flutter portion:

```
  Future<void> printSomething(GoogleMapController mapController) async {
    const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('flutter.native/helper');
    channel.invokeMethod('showToast', {'text': 'hello world'});
  }
```

I have no idea how to incorporate this into my kotlin code properly, and there aren't many examples out there. At least none that I could find. My ultimate goal is to be able to manipulate private fun getKMLResource() and set return as a directory I select from my flutter app.

Anybody know how to do this? Please help. Thank you.

Here's my add kml flutter function:

Here's how I select my .kml:

```
  Future<void> addKml(GoogleMapController mapController) async {
    const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('flutter.native/helper');
    try {
      int kmlResourceId = await channel.invokeMethod('KML');
      return mapController.channel.invokeMethod("map#addKML", <String, dynamic>{
        'resourceId': kmlResourceId,
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      throw 'Unable to plot map: ${e.message}';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you gotta follow these documentations:

[Writing custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

[Supporting the new Android plugins APIs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration)

Error:

> 'onMethodCall' overrides nothing

Means that you are trying override something that does not exist

In this situation, you have to implement missing classes that are found in the docs tutorial:

```
ActivityAware, FlutterPlugin, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
```

On:

> MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler

You can override (Kotlin snippet):

```
override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result)
```

That should fix your problem.

ActivityAware and FlutterPlugin are essentials for the new flutter upgrades and you can efficiently fix memory leaks with them.

```
class BubbleOverlayPlugin : ActivityAware, FlutterPlugin, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {


private var activity: Activity? = null
private var channel: MethodChannel? = null


   override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
    when (call.method) {
       //here lies the platform methods calls
    }
   }

    override fun onDetachedFromEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel?.setMethodCallHandler(null)
        //release resources
    }

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, channelName)
        channel?.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    }

    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        activity = binding.activity
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {
        //release resources
    }

    override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        activity = binding.activity
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
        //release resources
    }
}
```

You can check my source code from the plugin bubble_overlay, It is using the last docs recommendations.

Repo: [bubble_overlay repo](https://github.com/KohlsAdrian/bubble_overlay)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response... I will give this a shot tomorrow morning and get back to you.

Comment: Still struggling with this but I haven't given up yet.

Comment: nothing but errors and headaches. 'onMethodCall' overrides nothing.  Unresolved reference: showToast. @_@

Comment: Got both battery levels and load .kml working together... I'm using the same channel for both. Now I'm still trying to figure out how to use file picker to select a specific .kml in kotlin.

Comment: do you know if i can skip all this kotlin nonsense and just call my .kml with file picker through flutter? I added my flutter .kml function above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Android Studio, you simply need to open the project at the top of the project instead of in the `android/` folder.